# Handling variable fields in a CSV file with JSON?

Tags: postgresql, import, json, etl, csv

Im trying to figure out the engineering to get a CSV file into PostgreSQL.
Requirements:

1. The CSV has X number of predetermined required fields
2. The CSV file has Y number of dynamic fields

Example:

- **TenantCode,DomainCode,PersonCode,ExtraField1,ExtraField2,ExtraFieldN**
- "CUST1","STUD","C0001","Donald","Duck","M"
- "CUST1","STUD","C0002","Diana","Duck","F"

into this format (in PostgreSQL 10)

**TenantCode---DomainCode---PersonCode---ExtendedFields(JSONB)**

- CUST1---STUD---C0001---  {"ExtraField1":"Donald","ExtraField2":"Duck","ExtraFieldN":"M"}
- CUST1---STUD---C0002---   {"ExtraField1":"Diana","ExtraField2":"Duck","ExtraFieldN":"F"}

My original thought would be to (in Python) use Pandas to convert the entire file to json, then use PostgreSQL to COPY into a staging table, then use PostgreSQL SQL to parse out the required fields and insert into the destination table.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't do all that. I would just use python to transform the CSV file into another CSV where all the variable fields are a string of JSON.

Create the right table with the `jsonb` column and load direct into it. To do that use psql and `\COPY`. You can even create a program that reads from STDIN does the reformatting and outputs to `STDOUT`. And sits in the pipeline. Or you can write a quick perl script to get this done,

```
perl reformat.pl stupid1.csv stupid2.csv |
  psql -d test -e '\COPY mymastertable FROM stdin WITH ( format = csv )'
```

Or whatever.

Comment: So, Im my research over the past day, I had to adjust my thinking on what the solution is.  The solution is in-and-of-itself, not a json document.  It's a stream of json documents, with each document a series of CSV fields and a json string.  I can iterate over the CSV lines and then use the json.dump(row, output.file).   Thoughts?

Comment: I don't understand what you're talking about when you say stream, or what you're trying to do. I prefer you reduce it to a question, ask on a site and send me a link (I'm kind of tapped out) and perhaps others could help out.